# Does Apache Solr 3.x require a reload after posting a Schema.xml?

Tags: solr

I'm in a situation where I'm not sure if I can reload the server (I have no access to it), but I need to modify the schema. I'm posting a new schema.xml and it looks successful, but I'm not sure the schema has changed. It may be a mistake in my code, but I wanted to confirm that the core doesn't need to be reloaded to change the schema.

Thanks!